# Why not solve SVM with gradient descent instead of quadratic programming?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, svm, gradient-descent, kernel-trick

How is SVM optimization implemented in packages like Scikit-Learn? Clearly, SVM is a quadratic programming problem but why not just use gradient descent to update the parameters? Is it because we want to find the values of $\alpha_i$ and find support vectors? I found [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215524/is-gradient-descent-possible-for-kernelized-svms-if-so-why-do-people-use-quadr) but it doesn't seem to address my question.

Comment: You can solve it with least-squares as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_support-vector_machine that uses Lagrange multipliers (hence a gradient descent).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scikit-Learn's SVM is based on [LIBSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/) (from the [documentation of SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)), for which you can find the implementation document [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf). Specific solver information can be found in section 4.

Generally, gradient descent is a first-order method, which means it utilizes minimal information about the problem (only gradients) and thus converges slowly and might suffer from convergence issues. Taking into account more information about the problem, such as its quadratic nature and linear constraints, can yield faster and more robust algorithms. There are also specific quadratic optimization algorithms developed for SVM ([SMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization)).

Also note that Scikit-Learn has [SGDClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier), which is what you propose - SVM formulation with (stochastic) gradient descent optimization. You may find [this question comparing the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022187/scikit-learn-what-is-the-difference-between-svc-and-sgd) interesting.